# How to manage expiration of Kafka Groups

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, offset

I was trying to reset a consumer configuration by deleting it and letting my script recreate it later but I hit an error about new consumers not being deletable.

```
kafka@kafka-0:~$ ./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap kafka-0:9092 --delete --group etl
Option '[delete]' is only valid with '[zookeeper]'. Note that there's no need to delete group metadata for the new consumer as the group is deleted when the last committed offset for that group expires.
```

Now I'm wondering, what's the name of the consumer config option which controls the expiration from this error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The config is actually a broker config that determines how long to keep committed offsets around: `offsets.retention.minutes`. You may also want to adjust `offsets.retention.check.interval.ms` depending on the retention value you pick. ([reference](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs))

Comment: The default is value is 1440 minutes which is 24 hours/1 day